# set height of td to the height of the text

Tags: html, css

I want my elements to align to the top (elements in a table).
Now i have:

```
xxx yyy zzz
    yyy 
qqq fff ggg
```

and I want:

```
xxx yyy zzz
qqq yyy ggg
    fff
```

code:

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
td {vertical-align:top;padding-right:30px;width:20px;}
th tr {width:220px;}
</style>
<table border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>header</th>
            <th>header</th>
            <th>header</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>td1</td>
            <td>td2 bla bla bla bla bla bla blablablablablablablablablablabla</td>
            <td>td3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>td1</td>
            <td>td2</td>
            <td>td3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

I have a fiddle: [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ws6Aj/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: how should I then do it? drop the table and do it as div's??

Comment: What is the nature of the content? Tabular data or otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not bothered about the content remaining in the `x/y` position it has been set at in the table, I'm guessing this isn't tabular data, and therefore you shouldn't be using a table..

Therefore I would recommend using div's and CSS to position this content

http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/3-column-css-layout/

Comment: It still can be tabular data. Especially when I notice there are headings.

Comment: This could be column headings. Like "Latest News" etc.. I've never heard of tabular data which would shift to the record above just because it happens to be empty.

Comment: It might not be tabular data, but your assumption is wrong. `rowspan` / `colspan` is there for a reason :). Again you might be right.

Comment: I believe the reason `rowspan`/`colspan` are in place is for headings which group data. Although I have upvoted your answer, I don't believe your use of `rowspan` is what it was intended for.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible (at least not the way you have set it up).

You cannot 'break' table rows. This is just how tables work.

The only thing I can think of is use a `rowspan`, but I don't know whether that will help your specific case.

http://jsfiddle.net/ws6Aj/1/

**Update**

Please also note [Curt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730620/set-height-of-td-to-the-height-of-the-text/8730685#answer-8730751) whether you should be using a table or not.

Comment: Using `rowspan` is an option, but then you would need to set the height of a row explicitly. In this case, `tr:first-child + tr { height: 1.2em; }` would do that. The value `1.2` should be replaced by whatever value has been assigned to `line-height` (but if no value has been set to it, `1.2` should work reasonably).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela what is the `height` for?

Comment: without `height` setting browsers may make the row so high that there is too much space before the next row, as compared with the desired rendering here.

Answer (score 0):

Your cell contents *are* aligned to the top. You seem to want to move some contents in the second-row cells upwards. To achieve this, move the contents into the first row.